# How can we use a cartesian product in the definition for bipartite graph when its elements are tuples and edges can be sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I have learnt that in a bipartite graph, we can partition vertices into 2 sets $V_1$ and $V_2$, and $E \subseteq V_1 \times V_2$. However, the cartesian product is a set of tuples, and edges (in an undirected graph) are sets. So how can $E$ be a subset of this Cartesian product when a set is a different mathematical object than a tuple, so none of its elements are equal to any of the elements in the Cartesian product?

Comment: Edges in a directed graph are pairs; edges in an undirected graph are sets. I think this is what you meant to write. If so, you are correct that the quoted definition of bipartite doesn't work for undirected graphs. You have to say something like "for all $e \in E$, there exist $v_1 \in V_1$ and $v_2 \in V_2$ such that $e = \{v_1,v_2\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Core misconception** is this :
" ... edges (in a directed graph) are sets ... "

Edges are not really sets ( though we might have some way to achieve that , that is not the concern here )
Edges are ... Edges !
All of those Edges are in some Set , though the Edges themselves are not Sets.

This is true :
" ... a set is a different mathematical object than a tuple ... "
though it is not going to impact the Case that Edges are not Sets.

**Illustrative Example :**

[image: EDGES]

We have a Bi-Partite graph.

Nodes are in a Set $V=\{v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6,v_7\}$.
Here , neither $v_0$ nor $v_7$ is a Set. These are Nodes , nothing more , nothing less.

Edges are $E=\{ E_1 , E_2 , E_3 , \cdots \}$.
We can see the the Edges can be given in terms of the Nodes , like this :
$E=\{(v_0,v_4),(v_0,v_5),(v_1,v_4), \cdots \}$.
Here , too , neither $(v_0,v_4)$ nor $(v_3,v_5)$ is a Set. These are Edges , nothing more , nothing less.
We use "Names" ( like $E_1$ ) or "Constituents" ( like $(v_0,v_1)$ ) to refer to those Edges.

**In "Constituents" notation , we can see that the tuples are all in $V_1 \times V_2$ where $V_1$ & $V_2$ are the Partitions & all "Directions" are from $V_1$ to $V_2$. In other words , $E \subseteq V_1 \times V_2$.**

**ADDENDUM :**
Query is about Directed graphs.
In Case it is not Directed  graph , either **[[A]]** we have to first fix the order of writing the tuples ( ordered Pairs , where $E_1=(v_1,v_4)$ ) in the Cartesian Product or **[[B]]** we have to change the Cartesian Product to something else to generate something else ( unordered Pairs , where $E_1=(v_1,v_4)=(v_4,v_1)$ ) to handle the 2 orders.